# UITabBarにカスタムなbadgeをつけたい

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

UITabBarに周囲が白くなっている赤丸のbadgeをつけたいのですが、ググってもうまくやり方がわかりません。

下記のようなライブラリは、見つけたんですが、うまくできませんでした。
https://github.com/evgenyneu/swift-badge
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 標準のbadgeではなく自分で指定するということでしょうか？
[タブアイテムに赤丸以外のバッチが表示可能になりました](https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/ios10-tabbar-item/)

Comment: そうですね。
自分で作ったbadgeを用いたいです。
具体的には、赤丸の周りに白色で囲いたいです

Answer (score 0):

[UIBarItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibaritem/1616415-image)にimage(UIImage)プロパティがあるので、そこにUIGraphicsBeginImageContextで作成したUIImageをセットすればいけそうな気がします。

[画像とテキストの合成 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext](https://i-app-tec.com/ios/uigraphicsbeginimagecontext.html)

もしくはSF Symbolsを使って、やるとかですかね。
細かい色設定はおそらくできませんが

UIImage.withTintColor()を使って、SF Symbolsの色も設定可能です。
https://techlife.cookpad.com/entry/2021/01/05/custom-symbols-ja